# Convert a list tuples (index, list(features)) to a DataFrame with column values as booleans of features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a following data list:

`[(1, [1,2]), (2, [1,2]), (3,[1])]`

and would like to transform this into a pandas dataframe

```
   1   2  
1 True True
2 True True
3 True False
```

Is there a builtin method for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
index, data = zip(*[(1, [1,2]), (2, [1,2]), (3,[1])])
pd.DataFrame(list(data), index, [1, 2]).notnull()

      1      2
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really "built-in", but pretty quick:

```
l = [(1, [1,2]), (2, [1,2]), (3,[1])]

df = pd.DataFrame([ i[1] for i in l ], index = [ i[0] for i in l ]).notnull()
```

Output:

```
      0      1
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True  False
```

...if the column names don't absolutely need to be 1, 2.

and a shameless rip-off of @piRSquared's solution if they do need to be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ i[1] for i in l ], [ i[0] for i in l ], [ 1, 2 ]).notnull()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# use from_dict to load the list after converting it to a dict.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({e[0]:e[1] for e in l},orient='index')>0

      0      1
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True  False
```

If you want column name to be 1,2

```
df.columns=[1,2]

df
Out[231]: 
      1      2
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True  False
```